# Submit button not changing from disabled to enabled after Validation of field length

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React form with just a text area and a submit button. I set the submit button's state to disabled to begin with, and then after the user enters 100 chars or more I want to enable the Submit button.

The issue I'm having right now is that after I input more than 100 chars, the submit button remains disabled and doesn't change to enabled state.

This is the `updateFieldLength` function I am calling upon the textarea field's `onChange`.

```
const updateFieldLength = e => (
    setText(e.target.value), () => (
      validateFieldLength()
    )
  )
```

and this is the `validateFieldLength` function:

```
function validateFieldLength() {
    if (submitDisabled && text.length > 100) {
      setSubmitDisabled(false);
    } else if (!submitDisabled && text.length <= 100) {
      setSubmitDisabled(true);
    }
  }
```

Comment: can you add the rest of the components code?

Comment: hard to tell without seeing the rest of the code but couldn't you just pass in `disabled` prop based on text length on the submit button? you don't have to manage separate state. `disabled={text.length <= 100}`

Comment: That's a really good idea that simplifies it a whole lot. And it worked. Many thanks @andrewgi

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be that the onchange event is triggered only when textarea loses focus. I guess it would work with the oninput event, shown below

```js
const setBackground = (element, background) => {
  element.style.background = background;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="test-on-change" onchange="setBackground(this, 'green')" rows="10" cols="30">Example with onchange, start typing...</textarea>
<textarea id="test-on-input" oninput="setBackground(this, 'yellow')" rows="10" cols="30">Example with oninput, start typing...</textarea>
```

Comment: I just tried this out out of curiosity. It's not letting me input anything now. Do I need to have an onChange event in addition to the oninput event?

Comment: My bad, I should have mentioned this is React. It was tagged with both React and JS. I should have mentioned React in the q. I updated it to React's onInput but it behaves the same as onChange does, if I use the original code. Was worth trying out though.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job

```
import React from 'react'

const MyComponent = () => {
    const [text, setText] = useState('')

    const handleTextChange = e => {
        setText(e.target.value)
    }

    return(
        <>
            <textarea onChange={handleTextChange}>
                {text}
            </textarea>
            
            <button disabled={text.length < 100}> 
                Submit
            </button>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me why my original code above didn't work? I had already made this change as per the comment above.